# How did I move the taskbar to the top while it was locked?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I had the taskbar locked, and I was switching to a different window, when suddenly the taskbar moved from the bottom of the screen to the top. I must have done something by accident, I was able to move it to the bottom after unlocking it. But what was it I did that caused it to move to the top whilst it was locked?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to accidentally move the taskbar, is somehow pressing `alt+space` than `m` while the taskbar is selected (for example with `Win+t`), than an *arrow key* and moving your cursor to the top than clicking to fix it. But even this won't work unless you somehow right clicked the taskbar and pressed `l` than did that again to lock it.

This would be odd.
I suggest you check your system with an anti-malware software like [malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You most likely right clicked on an icon in the taskbar, then left clicked on the actual taskbar itself and moved the mouse causing it to jump to the top of the screen.

This article explains more of the details as to why it happens and also has a hotfix to fix it:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2877985/fix-locked-taskbar-moves-to-the-top-of-the-screen-in-windows-7-sp1-or